# how to keep dynamic ng-model with multiple objects creation

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the html from the server with I am generating the html in the view with ng-repeat like below

```html
<div class="col-lg-6"  ng-repeat="controls in steps.infos">
 <input type="text" ng-model="formData[controls.id]">
</div>
```

in my `controller` I have declared a variable `$scope.formData = {};`. It is all working fine. But here I want to create dynamic new `ng-model` which creates a new `object`. Can anyone help me on this how to create multiple object by setting dynamic ng-models in the view like -  `ng-model="formData.{{$index}}[controls.id]"`. I want to generate below JSON format dynamically using `ng-model`. is it possible?

```
{
   "0":{
      "5":"sdfasf"
   },
   "1":{
      "7":"sdfasf"
   }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39739957/4316707

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ng-model="formData['field_' + $index]"
```

If you'e nested loop than you can do something like.

```
ng-model="formData[$parent.$index]['field_' + $index]"
```

In your case, this might helps you.

```
ng-model="formData[$index][controls.id]"
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.home = {parent: {}};
  $scope.objectsList = [{
                'id':1,
                'name': 'Vikram',
                'Age': '25',
                'sex': 'M'
            }, {
                'id':2,
                'name': 'Quantum',
                'Age': '26',
                'sex': 'F'
            }, {
                'id':3,
                'name': 'Katty',
                'Age': '22',
                'sex': 'F'
            }];
  $scope.getJson = function(home){
    console.log(home);
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body  ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
<p ng-repeat="obj in objectsList">
    1st textbox<input type="text" ng-model="home.parent[$index][obj.id]" value="" />
  
  2nd textbox<input type="text" ng-model="home.parent[$index][obj.name]" value="" />
  
  <br/><br/>
</p>
  <button ng-click="getJson(home)">Get Json Object</button>
  {{parent}}
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: this create new object for each and every element where I want a new object for each and every index of ng-repeat. <div class="col-lg-6"  ng-repeat="controls in steps.infos">
 <input type="text" ng-model="formData[controls.id]" id="1"><input type="text" ng-model="formData[controls.id]" id="2">
</div>

Comment: something like this if there are two input elements in loop {"0":{"1":"sdfasf","2":"fjjj"},"1":{"7":"sdsafa","7":"askdk"}}

Comment: yes but for generating the html I have only one ng-repeat. If I use this ng-model="formData[$index][controls.id]" JSON  is getting generated in the following way {"0":{"5":"first_input"},"1":{"6":"second_input"}} for each input it is genrating the new object but I want for each ng-repeat something clubing and generating the single object for multiple inputs like {"0":{"5":"first_input","6":"second_input"},...}

Comment: @raghuveerambedkar : I've updated my answer, check the working example.

Comment: @raghuveerambedkar Did you check my answer ? is everything ok ?

Comment: yes I have just checked it. It is not changing anything. still creating the new object for each and every element and there is grand parent to all JSON is like below {"parent":{"0":{"5":"first_input"},"1":{"6":"second_input"}}}

Comment: I want to keep dynamic parent when I am looping through using ng-repeat. When the ng-repeat is running for first index it should create new object with all the input values in that single object and second index it should create another object. is this possible?

Comment: Can you please give me some example what you're looking for ? I just shown you a way, now you can do the changes in that object as per your need.